# Critical point for fusion curve

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, physical-chemistry, phase-diagram

In phase diagram, on vaporization curve there exists a critical point beyond which a gas can not be liquifies but why does fusion curve does NOT end at a critical point and continues to infinity?